# How to spec methods that exit or abort

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method being triggered from a CLI that has some logical paths which explicitly exit or abort. I have found that when writing specs for this method, RSpec marks it as failing because the exits are exceptions. Here's a a bare bones example:

```
def cli_method
  if condition
    puts "Everything's okay!"
  else
    puts "GTFO!"
    exit
  end
end
```

I can wrap the spec in a lambda with `should raise_error(SystemExit)`, but that disregards any assertions that happen inside the block. To be clear: I'm not testing the exit itself, but the logic that happens before it. How might I go about speccing this type of method?

Comment: Are wanting to test that "GTFO!" is being printed?

Comment: Yes, in this simplified example. Assume any arbitrary code in that else, though.

Comment: closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480537/how-can-i-validate-exits-and-aborts-in-rspec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put your assertions outside of the lambda, for example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :result

  def logic_and_exit
    @result = :bad_logic
    exit
  end
end

describe 'Foo#logic_and_exit' do
  before(:each) do
    @foo = Foo.new
  end

  it "should set @foo" do
    lambda { @foo.logic_and_exit; exit }.should raise_error SystemExit
    @foo.result.should == :logics
  end
end
```

When I run rspec, it correctly tells me:

```
expected: :logics
     got: :bad_logic (using ==)
```

Is there any case where this wouldn't work for you?

**EDIT:** I added an 'exit' call inside the lambda to hande the case where `logic_and_exit` doesn't exit.

**EDIT2:** Even better, just do this in your test:

```
begin
  @foo.logic_and_exit
rescue SystemExit
end
@foo.result.should == :logics
```

Answer (score 7):

New answer to cover Rspec 3's expect syntax.

### Testing the output

Just to test what you actually want (ie. you're not testing the exception, or a value response,) what has been output to STDOUT.

When `condition` is false

```
it "has a false condition" do
  # NOTE: Set up your condition's parameters to make it false
  expect {
    begin cli_method
    rescue SystemExit
    end
  }.to output("GTFO").to_stdout # or .to_stderr
end
```

When `condition` is true

```
it "has a true condition" do
  # NOTE: Set up your condition's parameters to make it true
  expect {
    begin cli_method
    rescue SystemExit
    end
  }.to output("Everything's okay!").to_stdout
end
```

Note that `output("String").to_...` can accept a `Regex` eg.

```
output(/^Everything's okay!$/).to_stdout
```

It can also capture from `stderr` eg.

```
output("GTFO").to_stderr
```

(Which would be a better place to send it, for the OP's example.)

### Testing the Exit

You can separately test that the false condition also raises `SystemExit`

```
it "exits when condition is false" do
  # NOTE: Set up your condition's parameters to make it false
  expect{cli_method}.to raise_error SystemExit
end

it "doesn't exit when condition is true" do
  # NOTE: Set up your condition's parameters to make it true
  expect{cli_method}.not_to raise_error SystemExit
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can wrap the spec in a lambda with should raise_error(SystemExit),
>   but that disregards any assertions that happen inside the block.

I don't see a difference putting tests inside or outside the lambda. In either case, the failure message is a bit cryptic:

```
def cli_method(condition)
  if condition
    puts "OK"
  else
    puts "GTFO"
    exit
  end
end

describe "cli_method" do
  context "outside lambda" do
    # passing
    it "writes to STDOUT when condition is false" do
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("GTFO")
      lambda {
        cli_method(false)
      }.should raise_error(SystemExit)
    end

    # failing
    it "does not write to STDOUT when condition is false" do
      STDOUT.should_not_receive(:puts).with("GTFO")
      lambda {
        cli_method(false)
      }.should raise_error(SystemExit)
    end
  end
  context "inside lambda" do
    # passing
    it "writes to STDOUT when condition is false" do
      lambda {
        STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("GTFO")
        cli_method(false)
      }.should raise_error(SystemExit)
    end

    # failing
    it "does not write to STDOUT when condition is false" do
      lambda {
        STDOUT.should_not_receive(:puts).with("GTFO")
        cli_method(false)
      }.should raise_error(SystemExit)
    end
  end
end

 # output
.F.F

Failures:

  1) cli_method outside lambda does not write to STDOUT when condition is false
     Failure/Error: lambda {
       expected SystemExit, got #<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<IO:0xb28cd8>).puts("GTFO")
           expected: 0 times
           received: 1 time>
     # ./gtfo_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) cli_method inside lambda does not write to STDOUT when condition is false
     Failure/Error: lambda {
       expected SystemExit, got #<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<IO:0xb28cd8>).puts("GTFO")
           expected: 0 times
           received: 1 time>
     # ./gtfo_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```