# How can I validate exit value in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method that will sometimes call `exit(numeric_value)`.

Is it possible for rspec to validate that when the method is invoked, the process is exiting with the correct value?

I have seen these other posts, but they do not answer this specific question.

- [How can I validate exits and aborts in RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480537/how-can-i-validate-exits-and-aborts-in-rspec)
- [How to spec methods that exit or abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019907/how-to-spec-methods-that-exit-or-abort)

Comment: You would need to stub out `exit`, or your program will actually *exit* when that line is encountered. You really shouldn't just be bailing out that way though. Raise an exception instead.

Comment: @meagar The ruby script I want to test with rspec is used in the context of an external framework (Sensu) that examines the exit value and acts accordingly.  So calling `exit` seems to be required in this case.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `exit` in Ruby actually *does* raise an Exception. Your question is a duplicate of the first link you posted, and the answer will work fine for you. Just catch the `SystemExit` exception. `lambda { whatever }.should raise_error SystemExit`, or just catch the `SystemExit` exception your self an inspect `.status` of the caught exception.
`

Comment: @meagar I know I can just catch the SystemExit exception.  The problem I don't know how to solve is: how to verify that we exited with status code 1, for example, or 2.

Comment: As I said: Test `.status` of the exception you catch.

Comment: @meagar Now I see what you were getting at, thanks for the info.  If you submit this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 8):

Given sample ruby code:

```
def it_will_exit
  puts "before exit"
  exit(false)
  puts "never get here"
end
```

rspec test case can be:

```
it "it must exit" do
  expect { it_will_exit }.raise_exception(SystemExit)
end

it "the exit value should be false" do
  begin
    it_will_exit
  rescue SystemExit=>e
    expect(e.status).to eq(1)
  end
end
```