# Test output to command line with RSpec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I want to do is run `ruby sayhello.rb` on the command line, then receive `Hello from Rspec`.

I've got that with this:

```
class Hello
  def speak
    puts 'Hello from RSpec'
  end
end

hi = Hello.new #brings my object into existence
hi.speak
```

Now I want to write a test in rspec to check that the command line output is in fact "Hello from RSpec"
and not "I like Unix"

NOT WORKING. I currently have this in my sayhello_spec.rb file

```
require_relative 'sayhello.rb' #points to file so I can 'see' it

describe "sayhello.rb" do
  it "should say 'Hello from Rspec' when ran" do        
    STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with('Hello from RSpec')    
  end
end
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 26):

Here's a pretty good way to do this. Copied from the [hirb test_helper source](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb):

```
def capture_stdout(&block)
  original_stdout = $stdout
  $stdout = fake = StringIO.new
  begin
    yield
  ensure
    $stdout = original_stdout
  end
  fake.string
end
```

Use like this:

```
output = capture_stdout { Hello.new.speak }
output.should == "Hello from RSpec\n"
```

Comment: To build on this:

    def expect_stdout(string, &block); 
      output = capture_stdout(&block); 
      output.should include string; 
    end

Answer (score 2):

The `quietly` command is probably what you want (cooked into ActiveSupport, see docs at [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org)).  This snippet of RSpec code below shows how to ensure there is no output on stderr while simultaneously silencing stdout.

```
quietly do                        # silence everything
  commands.each do |c|
    content = capture(:stderr) {  # capture anything sent to :stderr
      MyGem::Cli.start(c)
    }
    expect(content).to be_empty, "#{c.inspect} had output on stderr: #{content}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

So you don't have to change your main ruby code I just found out you can do something like this:

```rb
def my_meth
  print 'Entering my method'
  p 5 * 50
  puts 'Second inside message'
end

describe '#my_meth' do
  it 'puts a 2nd message to the console' do
    expect{my_meth}.to output(/Second inside message/).to_stdout
  end
end
```

When checking for a desired output text I used it inside / / like a `Regexp` because after many many maaany tests and looking around, the STDOUT is everything that is outputted so I found it to be better to use Regex so you could check the whole STDOUT for the exact text that you want.
Like I put it, it works in the terminal just perfect.

//Just had to share this, it took me days to figure it out.

Answer (score -5):

```
it "should say 'Hello from Rspec' when run" do        
  output = `ruby sayhello.rb`
  output.should == 'Hello from RSpec'   
end
```