# How to test RSpec tests output in command line

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm running tests that returns `puts` to console with return value as `nil`

Problem is that I'm now getting `puts` output coming out whenever I run tests with RSpec.

How would you test this output and make sure no output is showing up in test console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test output to command line with RSpec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349270/test-output-to-command-line-with-rspec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to refactor the code so that it takes an IO object as input and gives its output by calling `puts` on that.  In normal use, use $stdout but in your tests use a StringIO object.

If that is not feasible, you might consider inside your tests defining a special puts method in the class being tested.  This would hide the real puts method.