# Adding rspec to command line Ruby program

Tags: ruby, command-line, rspec, stdout

I'm doing a coding challenge and have a simple 1 file ruby program (e.g. `processor.rb`) that accepts arguments via a file passed on the command line, like so:

> $ ruby processor.rb < inputs.txt

I'm fairly lost with how to implement tests (I'm used to having it all ready to go in a Rails app). Do I add them to the same file (`processor.rb`)? Do I create a separate test file and run that with a separate command?

Any help much appreciated. On the surface this might seem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349270/test-output-to-command-line-with-rspec) but none of those answers are what I'm looking for.

Comment: As a matter of convention, you'd make a directory `spec`, and in it `processor_spec.rb`; but it is not a law.

Comment: You can use [`aruba-rspec`](https://github.com/livinginthepast/aruba-rspec) *Bridge RSpec and Aruba/ArubaDoubles to test command-line tools*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it, but this is what I do. Run `rspec --init` in the top level directory of your project, which will create a `spec` directory containing a `spec_helper.rb` file. It also creates a `.rspec` hidden file in your top level directory, which will automatically require your helper when running `rspec`.

You can then start creating spec files in the spec directory. By convention, files are named `<subject>_spec.rb`. For example, if you have a class called `FileTree` (and therefore a file named `file_tree.rb`), your corresponding spec file will be `file_tree_spec.rb`.

You can organise your specs in directories - it makes no difference. However, I tend to mimic the structure of the code that I'm testing.