# How to write test case for program exit

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a code snippet in which i am terminating the program when i receive `exit` input from `STDIN` using gets. How do i write the rspec test case for the same.

Below is the code snippet.

```
class CommandProcessor
    attr_accessor :input
    attr_accessor :operation
    def parser
        while true
            input = gets.chomp
            operation = input.split(' ')[0]
            param = input.split(' ')[1]
            if operation.eql? 'exit'
                exit
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Below is my attempt.

```
describe "CommandProcessor" do
    it "will exit on input exit" do
        cmd = CommandProcessor.new
        cmd.parser
        expect { it_will_exit }.raise_exception(SystemExit) 
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

I tried Leonid Mirsky's method before and got this error :

```
lib/calculator.rb:37:in `parser': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480537/how-can-i-validate-exits-and-aborts-in-rspec

Comment: What does `it_will_exit` do?

Answer (score 1):

You can stub the `gets` method on the cmd object itself.

Use the following spec code:

```
describe "CommandProcessor" do
  it "will exit on input exit" do
    cmd = CommandProcessor.new
    cmd.stub(:gets) {"exit\n"}
    expect { cmd.parser }.to raise_error SystemExit
  end
end
```

Comment: Change `gets.chomp` to `gets.to_s.chomp` to avoid that error.